# Asynchronous database calls in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, celery

I'm currently in the process of scaling a project I've been working on up, and today is the first time that I've had a worker node attempt to communicate with my MySQL database in asynchronous fashion. To elaborate, while developing this project I've been using Celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/) on a local VM that had a single core, and therefore only ran a single worker process at a time. Now that I've bumped up my number of concurrent workers, the database connector is dying (and painfully at that). A sample output of one of the errors that I'm seeing is shown below:

```
[2015-11-18 17:21:40,457: DEBUG/Worker-4] Task runner of class SeedPreparationTaskRunner initialized with Task ID 6.
[2015-11-18 17:21:40,458: INFO/Worker-4] Now running task runner for Task 6.
[2015-11-18 17:21:40,475: DEBUG/Worker-5] Task runner of class SeedPreparationTaskRunner initialized with Task ID 7.
[2015-11-18 17:21:40,480: INFO/Worker-5] Now running task runner for Task 7.
[2015-11-18 17:21:40,481: ERROR/Worker-4] Exception raised during execution of Task 6. Exception was This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.. S
tack trace was Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/websight/tasknode/celery/celerytasks.py", line 21, in run_task_with_id
    TaskManager.run_task(task_id=task_id)
```

From what I can tell, the problem is that this line of code is being run at almost the exact same time in two separate processes:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    task = Task.by_id(session, self.task_id)
```

And the by_id method is shown below:

```
@classmethod
def by_id(cls, session, input_id):
    return session.query(cls).filter_by(id=input_id).first()
```

I don't know enough about how the database API / connectors work, but I am guessing that the MySQL database connector I am using doesn't like multiple processes trying to issue queries through it at the same time.

So, that being said, I am wondering the following:

1. Does my assessment of what is actually breaking here sound correct?
2. If so, is there a MySQL connector that I can use in Python that would allow me to send many database queries to the same database at the same time?
3. Do any other databases (other than MySQL) support this sort of asynchronous querying out-of-the-box (as I can migrate to another database without issue)?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Shame nobody answered this one, did you solve it? Perhaps adding your own answer would be helpful. The error says "This result object does not return rows". What is `cls` ? Is it a SELECT or some SQL that returns rows? If it does not the `filter_by` and `first` methods won't work on it. If it was the same code apart from adding workers, then maybe you can't run multiple async queries on the same connection object. You would need one per celery worker.